# double template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17, variadic-templates

Here is what my class looks like :

```
template<typename ...events_t, std::uint32_t ...stackDepth>
class Module {
    protected: std::tuple<EventHandler<events_t, stackDepth>...> evtHandlers;
    public: Module(std::tuple<EventHandler<events_t, stackDepth>...> _evtHandlers) : 
         evtHandlers{_evtHandlers}{ /* ... */ }
    // ...
}
```

I am constrained to give the `EventHandler` a pair of template arguments, one being the handled event type and the other one an `std::uint32_t` for the task's stack depth.

The double template parameter pack cannot compile as-is, but I could not find a trick that would do.
Is there any way to make this work cleanly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template variadic parameter, for a template class/struct, must be at the end of the list of template parameters. So, directly, you can use only one.

But you can wrap one (or both) your variadic packs with, by example, `std::tuple`, for types, and, `std::integer_sequence`, for integer values.

Unfortunately, you have to use template specialization: you have to declare the main template receiving, by example, a couple of types

```
template <typename, typename>
class Module;
```

and a specialization that uses the single typename as template wrapper as follows

```
template <typename ... event_t, std::uint32_t ... stackDepth>
class Module<std::tuple<event_t...>, 
             std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, stackDepth...>>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

Given that you can place a variadic list at the end, you can avoid the second wrapper, so, by example,

```
template <typename, std::uint32_t...>
class Module;

template <typename ... event_t, std::uint32_t ... stackDepth>
class Module<std::tuple<event_t...>, stackDepth...>>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

Given that, if I understand correctly, the types (`event_t`) and the numbers (`stackDepth`) are related and that you have a template class/struct that accept a single type and a single number as template parameter (`Event_Handler`), I suppose you can directly use `Event_Handler` as variadic parameter.

I mean something as follows (full compiling example)

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename, std::uint32_t>
struct Event_Handler
 { };

template <typename...>
class Module;

template <typename ... event_t, std::uint32_t ... stackDepth>
class Module <Event_Handler<event_t, stackDepth>...>
 {
   // ...
 };

int main ()
 {
   Module<Event_Handler<int, 0u>, Event_Handler<long, 1u>>  m;
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> Actually I'd like to take it not as a pure template parameter but as an instance in the constructor. Is this possible with this trick ?

If I understand correctly, you're looking for "template deduction guides", available starting from C++17 (and you tagged C++17, so should works for you.

The following is a full (C++17) compiling example; the "explicit deduction guide" is the construct immediately before the `main()`

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename, std::uint32_t>
struct Event_Handler
 { };

template <typename...>
class Module;

template <typename ... event_t, std::uint32_t ... stackDepth>
class Module <Event_Handler<event_t, stackDepth>...>
 {
   public: 
      Module (Event_Handler<event_t, stackDepth>...)
       { }
 };

// explicit deduction guide
template <typename ... event_t, std::uint32_t ... stackDepth>
Module (Event_Handler<event_t, stackDepth>...)
   -> Module<Event_Handler<event_t, stackDepth>...>;

int main ()
 {
   Module  m(Event_Handler<int, 0u>{}, Event_Handler<long, 1u>{});
 }
```

Comment: Would this allow template type deduction ? I'd like to build my `module` from a simple tuple of `EventHandler`s, without having to re-specify their `stackDepth`s

Comment: @Magix - Answer improved with an example using a variadic list of `Event_Handler`s. And yes, the template type deduction works. Template number deduction also.

Comment: This (almost) works wonders. Still have a few errors I need to fix, but the blocking problem seems gone. I cannot thank you enough !

Comment: Actually I'd like to take it not as a pure template parameter but as an instance in the constructor. Is this possible with this trick ? I've been fiddling with it without success (see question edit)

Comment: @Magix - Not completely sure to understand but... answer improved.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to supply two lists explicitly, but you can capture them using a specialization:

```
template<typename A, typename B> class C;
template<typename ...As, typename ...Bs>
class C<std::tuple<As...>, std::tuple<Bs...>>
{
    ...
}
```